# How do I enforce this constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unique-constraint

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Category
(
  LogId int NULL,
  Name varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
```

Two categories with different `LogId`s may have the same `Name`, but a category may not have the same name as a category with a null `LogId`.

Is there a way to enforce this constraint?

I tried creating a unique index on this view:

```
create view Category_LogId_Name
  with schemabinding
as
select
  LogId,
  Name
from
  dbo.Category
where
  LogId is null
union all 
select
  b.LogId,
  a.Name
from
  dbo.Category a
  cross join dbo.Log b
where
  a.LogId is null
```

But trying to create the index:

```
create unique clustered index un_Category_LogId_Name on Category_LogId_Name (LogId, Name)
```

produces this error:

> Cannot create index on view 'Category_LogId_Name' because it contains one or more UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT operators. Consider creating a separate indexed view for each query that is an input to the UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT operators of the original view.

Is there a different approach?

Comment: You could use a [`CHECK` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx) for this, but they are not very performant.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid them.

Comment: Don't think you can, not for this requirement (unless you are willing to delegate checking to the application).

Comment: That's where it's enforced now. Was hoping to move it to the database.

Comment: I suggest using a `CHECK` constraint and testing. It may be performant enough - you never know...

Comment: Could split it into two tables.  The first with a PK on LogID, Name with LogID not null.  The second table just Name as PK.  With Union and Intersect the queries will not be bad.

Comment: @Blam: How would that make it easier to enforce the constraint?

Comment: You stated a desire avoid a check constraint and I assumed based on performance.  This is the most performant way (I can think) to enforce those enforce those constraints.  The app would need to put data in the correct table but the app would not be allowed to enter or create bad data.  And you are not wasting space on null int.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how to enforce the constraint using two tables as you've described?

Comment: Oded, a check constraint is not useful here, as it could only check the row against itself, not against other rows in the table.

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading you right, you have two constraints:

1. Category Name + LogId must be unique; if LogId is null, Name must be unique.
2. A given Category Name may be associated with a non-null LogId, or a null LogId, but not both.

You enforce (1) with a vanilla `UNIQUE` constraint, like so:

```
alter table dbo.Category add constraint UQ_Category (Name, LogId)
```

Unlike `PRIMARY KEY` constraints, `UNIQUE` constraints allow nullable keys, and treat nulls as instances of the same "value". Thus, this data would be allowed:

```
insert dbo.Category (LogId, Name) values (null, 'Name1') -- ok
insert dbo.Category (LogId, Name) values (1, 'Name1') -- ok
insert dbo.Category (LogId, Name) values (2, 'Name1') -- ok
insert dbo.Category (LogId, Name) values (3, 'Name1') -- ok
```

but this would be rejected after the first insert:

```
insert dbo.Category (LogId, Name) values (null, 'Name1') -- ok
insert dbo.Category (LogId, Name) values (null, 'Name1') -- error
insert dbo.Category (LogId, Name) values (null, 'Name1') -- error
insert dbo.Category (LogId, Name) values (null, 'Name1') -- error
```

Then for (2), you need something to enforce *exclusivity*, so that if a Name is associated w/ a null LogId, it cannot be associated w/ a non-null LogId, and vice-versa. For this, you group by Name and the nullity of LogId in an indexed view:

```
create view dbo.MakeItExclusive
with schemabinding as
select Name
     , case when LogId is null then 1 else 0 end as HasNullLogIds
     , count_big(*) as _rowcount
from dbo.Category
group by Name
       , case when LogId is null then 1 else 0 end
go

create unique clustered index CU_MakeItExclusive on dbo.MakeItExclusive (Name)
go
```

Since the view has a `GROUP BY` clause, SQL Server requires `COUNT_BIG(*)` in the `SELECT` clause to create the index.

Beyond that, it's pretty straight-forward: group by Name and LogId-nullness, and then ensure that Name is unique in the results. If a Name were associated w/ both a null LogId and a non-null LogId, there would be two rows, violating the constraint.